# CSS not showing up on Wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress

I just made a demo website on Wordpress. It is acting weirdly on every computers on my workplace. On every other PCs which do not belong to the network of my workplace it shows up fine.

Here is what exactly happens, when I apply a theme, it shows up for the first time, as soon as I reload it, all the css styles disappear.

Link to the site [www.bkmehta.xyz](http://www.bkmehta.xyz)

I just want to know the possible issues. Is my workplace blocking the content?

What I have tried so far:

- Tried applying different themes
- Changed all the file permissions to 755.

Console Error Screenshot :[Console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Ir9.png)

Comment: It seems some firewall preventing your things. For me site is working with well design.

Comment: I also think that can be the issue. Trying to find a work around @HelpingHands

Comment: try to check site in browser private window.

Comment: Please check if any errors appears in the `console` panel. (`F12` in `Google Chrome`)

Comment: @MoshFeu The console does show some errors. I cant seem to figure it out why it is showing. I will add a screenshot of the errors

Comment: You server response a `403` error for this resources. It's very strange that it block just for you. Did you try to view the site with other browsers or in [`incognito`](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?source=gsearch&hl=en) mode?

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok to me.  Try restarting the browser or clearing the browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me, I hard refresh the site.

Mac: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>

Everything else: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>